# grappelli NestedTabularInline how to disable "add another..." button

Tags: django, django-admin, django-grappelli

I am using grappeli for my admin, I have nested models using NestedTabularInline

I would like to have only list without "add another..." in the bottom.

Or how to change `grp-add-handler` so that it is hidden, without need to build custom template..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve it django-grappelli independently, just use the new functionallity of django admin, and for your inline class

```
max_num=0
```